# python web server recommendation

Tags: python, http, web

Still learning python, and want to build a web project.

I wonder if there is any web server implemented in python that could be used in practice?

I know [simplehttpserver](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html), which is too simple.

Apache and Nginx, they might be too complicated, and they're not python.

### addition

Sorry if I'm not making it clear. I'm working on a simple http file browser much like ubuntu repository where people download files. simplehttpserver works, but I want to use more features, 
like process request before it gets to a file, and customized url routing .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear exactly what you're asking. There's web frameworks for writing Python web applications, like Django or Flask or Bottle or Pyramid, but they're usually behind things like Apache and Nginx in practice.

Comment: What features do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deploying WSGI applicaitons you may look into [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), which is written in Python.

Or if you are interested in writing an Asynchronous application, you may look into [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) which comes with it's own server.

Please update your question in details i.e. your use case, and with particular problems you may face, otherwise it'd be considered not constructive.

Comment: Tornado might be the thing I'm looking for, thx.